# Repeat/Scroll texture on CubeMap

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, lwjgl, skybox

I need a method to scroll an image across all sides of a cube map in a way similar to scrolling a UV texture across a water's texture to give the appearance of movement by shifting the normals. I want to cause certain areas of the skybox to grow in intensity or lower to mimic a twinkle effect for the stars. I'm using a simple perlin noise map to do it, and I just need to find a way to scroll the texture on each side of the cubemap.

I've tried to shift the texture coordinates on the `samplerCube` in GLSl, but it seemed to move the entire cube instead of just changing the coordinates that the cube gets the texture from.

I also tried using a regular `sampler2D`, but that resulted in a screen of pure grey somehow.

What can I do to get this effect?

Comment: No need to ask this again, you can just edit your original question to provide the additional information.

Comment: I don't believe my first one properly explained what I was looking for and my attempts to make it work, so I decided to make a new post with additional information and more context specifically.

Comment: I'm interested and I'm sure that many others as well. So where is this "original" question?